# breaking out of a fixed width parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm attempting to break out of the #content div to go full width. The height isn't a problem, I guess since it's not set here. Is it possible to break the child div out of the parent div in this instance. I've tried making the width greater than 1370px and also a width of 100%.

```
div.container {
            width: 1370px;
        }

        ##content {
            width: 1370px;
        }

        ##header,
        ##footer-cnt div.container {
            padding-left: 200px;
        }

        ##footer-cnt div.container {
            width: 1168px;
        }

        body {
            background: ##eeeeee;
        }
```

Comment: i believe you need to set the display property - like ```display: block```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML? Also why so many `#` symbols?

Comment: Not sure about the #s. I didn't right the code. Code to come.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `##` is not a css thing. If you are trying to refer to elements using the id selector, you want to use a single `#`.

There are a couple ways to give the impression that a child is broken out from a parent. Each has their own use-case depending on what you need to do.

## Way 1: Close parent, do child, re-open parent

This is good little hack when you are in a text editor or some other environment where you can't control the parent. You would do something like this:

```
</div><!-- close parent -->
<div class="child"> Child content
<div class="parent">
```

## Way 2: Use absolute/fixed positioning with css

This works in certain use cases, and gives the *appearance* that the child is outside of the parent, though as far as the DOM is concerned, it's still in there.

## Way 3: use javascript

A simple jQuery script can remove the child from the parent. Given:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"> Child stuff </div>
</div>
```

You could do:

```
jQuery(function($){
    var child = $('.child').detach();
    $('.parent').after(child);
});
```

Which would take child out of parent and move to just after it in a sibling-location in the DOM.